# Karate Listener support

Tags: testing, automation, karate

Does karate provide any listener support where I can intercept any specific things like rest calls?

This is more like added customization we want to perform apart from what the karate provides. There will be always something or other we need to customize based on the need.

Say that I have 10000 test cases running in parallel and using karate parallel runner I get a nice report with the time it takes for each step and test cases. One of my service is getting called multiple times and I wanted to know what is the average time the service takes out of all the calls. What is the maximum or minimum time it takes.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Karate Hooks](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) will get you what you need - if you write a function to aggregate the `responseTime`.

I'm willing to look at introducing this feature if needed, but you'll have to make a proposal on what the syntax should look like. Feel free to open a feature request. Today we do have `configure headers` that is like a "before" for all requests. Maybe something along those lines.